# Income tax treatment for salary earned in Hong Kong and India in single year

Tags: income-tax, india, hong-kong

Can somebody help me in understanding tax treatment of my salary income if I earn in India as well as Hong Kong during a single year with duration of stay in India being more than 182 days?

Answer (score 1):

If your stay in India is more than 182 days in a financial year, you would be treated as Resident Indian for tax purposes and your complete salary worldwide would be subject to taxes in India. i.e. You would be taxed in India for the salary you earn in Hong Kong.

Please consult a CA to understand if there are any benefits and how the taxes can be paid to Income tax authorities in India.